# nginx proxy_pass behavior when downloading a file

Tags: nginx, download, proxypass

I have a question regarding the behavior of proxy_pass in nginx. 
Let's suppose the nginx config has the following location property:

```
location /a.mp4 {
    proxy_pass http://3rd_party_domain/a.mp4;
}
```

(Note that the syntax might be incorrect, but you can get what I'm trying to say)

Question: When an user tries to download a.mp4 on my domain, where the actual traffic comes from? I can think of the following possible scenarios:

```
#1 3rd_party_domain -----> client
#2 3rd_party_domain -----> my_domain -----> client
```

I hope #1 is the case here, but wondering whether actually behavior is something like #2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes through my_domain, the client uses my_domain like a "tunnel".

Comment: thanks. then what should i use instead of 'proxy_pass' to completely redirect the given request to the 3rd party domain?

Comment: You have to include the the video source in your html page using `http://3rd_party_domain/a.mp4`. In this case, the browser will connect to 3rd_party directly.

Comment: There's no way to do that via nginx? Basically, I want to hide the 3rd_party_domain url, so a little bit hesitate to embed the 3rd-party-domain url in the html page. What I'm thinking is: client ----> my_domain --(redirect)--> 3rd_party_domain ----(eventually)--> client.

Comment: You can olnly hide 3rd_pary with proxypass. Every other method like embedd, redirect will show the original source.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I had the same scenario and found a different solution.
If you're using Google Cloud Storage or AWS S3, You can use a signed-URL download files via a load-balancer, which is connected to a bucket as a backend service.

[Using singed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

The file name can be static -
[using file metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026132/google-cloud-storage-download-a-file-with-a-different-name)

Or dynamic -
[using dynamic file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286724/google-cloud-storage-signed-url-forced-response-disposition)