# How to get response-content-type working for Google Cloud Storage signedUrl

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a .pdf object stored in Google Cloud Storage with C*ontent-Type = application/octet-stream*.

When giving temporary access through a signed URL, I extend the URL with:

```
&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf
```

Nevertheless, the response coming back from Google Cloud Storage still contains *Content-Type = application/octet-stream*

Inspecting the request + response through the browser confirms this behaviour.

According to the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#responsecontenttype) the response-content-type should ensure *Content-Type = application/pdf* in my example.

For another usecase, I am succesfully making use of the *Content-Disposition* override via *response-content-disposition*, so I am very curious why the response-content-type is not working for me.

Anyone any idea what I am missing to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Storage Signed URL forced response disposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286724/google-cloud-storage-signed-url-forced-response-disposition)

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#string-components) signed URLs are not authenticated GET requests that support content-type override.

> Query String Parameters like response-content-disposition and response-content-type are not verified by the signature. To force a Content-Disposition or Content-Type in the response, set those parameters in the object metadata using gsutil or the XML/JSON API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After some more investigation I stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286724/google-cloud-storage-signed-url-forced-response-disposition which clearly states that the response-content-type will only work in case it is not provided on the object meta-data. Strange.... since the Content-Type seems to be automatically defaulted to application/octet-stream if you don't provide it explicitely. Even if I try to blank the Content-Type using gsutil it gets defaulted. So what is the use of response-content-type I wonder.

Comment: Hi @PhilippeVerheyen as you found an answer, I suggest you post it and accept it after two days