# How to force Google Storage file to have `content-disposition: inline` instead of `attachment`?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, elixir

I'm using [GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Api.Objects.storage_objects_insert_simple](https://hexdocs.pm/google_api_storage/GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Api.Objects.html#storage_objects_insert_simple/7) to upload files to Google Storage. However, it seems that no matter what I do, the `content-disposition` HTTP response header is being set to `attachment` which forces browsers to download a file rather than displaying it in a browser tab.

Here's my usage:

```
{:ok, object} =
  GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Api.Objects.storage_objects_insert_simple(
    gconn,
    "my-uploads-bucket",
    "multipart",
    %{
      name: Path.basename(path),
      contentType: content_type,
      contentDisposition: "inline" # <-- this doesn't seem to have an effect
    },
    path
  )
```

Does anyone know how to force the content disposition header to have a value of `inline`?

## Update

After inspecting the value of `object`, I'm seeing the following:

```
%GoogleApi.Storage.V1.Model.Object{
  acl: nil,
  bucket: "my-uploads-bucket",
  cacheControl: nil,
  componentCount: nil,
  contentDisposition: "inline", # <-- !!!
  contentEncoding: nil,
  contentLanguage: nil,
  contentType: "image/png",
  crc32c: "MGa01Q==",
  ...
```

However, after fetching a file via `curl -I <url>`, I see the following:

```
HTTP/2 200 
...
content-type: image/png
content-disposition: attachment
...
```

Comment: Do you get the same behavior even after forcing the `Content-Disposition` metadata with [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta)? There is at least [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286724/google-cloud-storage-signed-url-forced-response-disposition) for issues between that specific header and at least Signed URLS (that I believe you are not using) that I believe you might find useful.

Comment: It might be an issue with the library itself though. In which case I recommend you to open an issue [here](https://github.com/googleapis/elixir-google-api/tree/master/clients/storage).

Comment: @DanielOcando Thank you for your responses. I'm not using Signed URLs because these URLs should be accessible to anyone who has the URL and no authentication is required. Is it possible that there is some configuration needed within Google Cloud to set the content disposition header to `inline`?

Comment: If you use `gsutil setmeta -h "Content-Disposition: inline" gs://[YOUR-BUCKET]/[YOUR-OBJECT]` do you still get this behavior? As advised [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions#options) the value for the Content-Disposition header is stored as object metadata and used in future requests on the object.

Comment: So, it seems like my mistake here was in using the `mediaLink` field as the URL. This URL even has `download` as part of the URL: `https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/...`. If I instead use `name` field to build the URL, then it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like my mistake here was in using the mediaLink field as the URL. This URL even has download as part of the URL: `https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/....`

If I instead use name field to build the URL, then it works as expected.

```
send_resp(
  conn,
  200,
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/" <> object.name
)
```