# How to generate a presigned URL with content-type disposition using GCS Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-bucket

In the Amazon S3 SDK, when generating a presigned URL, I can generate a URL setting the content-disposition, but I cannot find a similar way of configuring these options using Google.

The method call available to us is:

```
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google-cloud-storage/0.20.0/Google/Cloud/Storage/File#signed_url-instance_method
```

I am trying to upload a file directly to a Google bucket and not via my Rails server, and want to set the content-disposition of the file being uploaded via the presigned URL. Is there a way of doing this? Is there a way of setting object meta data via a presigned URL?

```
require "google/cloud"

gcloud = Google::Cloud.new
storage = gcloud.storage

bucket = storage.bucket "my-todo-app"
file = bucket.file "avatars/heidi/400x400.png"
shared_url = file.signed_url
# The parameters it takes is: signed_url(method: nil, expires: nil, content_type: nil, content_md5: nil, issuer: nil, client_email: nil, signing_key: nil, private_key: nil)

# how do we add content_disposition?
# how do we add object meta data?
```

Comment: I could only find that you can set metadata in already uploaded objects which I suppose is not what you would want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for the same answer, and so far I have found this other Stack Overflow article, which doesn't directly address Ruby SDK, but it does offer a good piece of information.

[Google Cloud Storage: download a file with a different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026132/google-cloud-storage-download-a-file-with-a-different-name)

> You can also generate signed URLs that include the response-content-disposition query parameter. Then the users will be making authorized requests to download the resource.

So it appears that you can add the query parameter `?response-content-disposition=[disposition-string-urlencoded]` to the resulting signed string.

So, I looked at the File object definition in the Ruby SDK and it appears you can do this:

```rb
file.content_dispostion = "attachment" # or whatever your disposition is
url = file.signed_url
```

NOTE: If you read my entry before I edited it, my apologies.

Comment: Here's the File#content_disposition definition in the documentation for your reference:
https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-storage/latest/Google/Cloud/Storage/File.html#content_disposition=-instance_method

Comment: Any luck with this solution?

Comment: oh dear i may have missed the edit, but i appreciate your answer. in the end, i gave up and just ran with the AWS's `s3` offering. probably a good decision in the end: GCS has too many issues regarding its uptime, and API is less developed than AWS.