# GCP cloud storage get downloadable url

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a public bucket, that I use to host public user content.

I want to give users the ability to download those files, by clicking a link, which opens the gcp page, that starts the download automatically. For this the content-disposition header needs to be set.

I would also like to set the filename of the downloaded file.

Is there a way to handle this within gcp?

I know I could generate a signed url: [Google Cloud Storage: download a file with a different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026132/google-cloud-storage-download-a-file-with-a-different-name), and set the desired headers, but I don't think this is the proper solution. From my understanding signed urls should be used, when accessing protected resources. Is there a way to get the download link easily?

I currently handle this on my own server, but I would like to let gcp handle it.
Here is a demo url of a cloud file: https://storage.googleapis.com/just-demo-bucket-14512/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_5MB.mp4

```
router.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=cool.mp4");
    request('https://storage.googleapis.com/just-demo-bucket-14512/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_5MB.mp4').pipe(res);
})
```

Comment: I don't understand. You have a public buket, why do you want to use the singedURL? And the content disposition is the right thing to do. You can permanently set it into Cloud Storage to prevent its addition in your code.

Comment: I want to set the content-disposition header on the fly. Setting it via a GET parameter would be perfect.

Comment: In the `GET parameter`, you means when you get the file from storage, you would like to something like `https://storage.googleapis.com/path/to/file?content-disposition=...` right?

Comment: This GET parameter would be perfect.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this.

Comment: Well that is unfortunate. I guess I'll have to use my own server as a proxy. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want a static content disposition, you can use the header of Cloud Storage. But is you want something dymanic, you have to put a server in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the content-disposition header on the fly, in other words:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/path/to/file?content-disposition=...
```

Then the answer is No; you cannot do this.

If you want a static content disposition, you can use the header of Cloud Storage but if you want something dynamic, you have to put a server in front of it.

However, if you feel strongly that this must be handled by the Cloud Storage API, you may raise a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) by specifying how this should be implemented and the added value it would have.